# How to make a block for header font styling at customizer via function.php?

Tags: theme-customizer

I am trying to make a section block to change font size at the customizer for the header, I can change font color with generate_css but not able to change size?
my code for changing color is bellow, I need help to make code for changing size.

```
class header_font_color {
    public static function register ( $wp_customize ) {

        $wp_customize->add_setting('header_emakers_fontcolor', array(
            'default' => 'No'
        ));

        $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'header_emakers_fontcolor-control', array(
            'label' => 'Display the Header Font Color?',
            'section' => 'colors',
            'settings' => 'header_emakers_fontcolor',
            'type' => 'select',
            'choices' => array('No'=> 'No', 'Yes' => 'Yes')
        )));



        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_emakers_fontcolor',
            array(
                'default'    => '#000000',
                'type'       => 'theme_mod',
                'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
                'transport'  => 'refresh',
                'sanitize_callback'  => 'esc_attr',
            )
        );

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'mytheme_header_emakers_fontcolor',
            array(
                'label'      => __( 'Header Font Color', 'customtheme' ),
                'settings'   => 'header_emakers_fontcolor',
                'priority'   => 10,
                'section'    => 'colors',
            )
        ) );

    }


    public static function header_outputt() {
        ?>

        <style type="text/css">

            <?php self::generate_css('.header-main *',  'color', 'header_emakers_fontcolor'); ?>
        </style>

        <?php
    }


    public static function generate_css( $selector, $style, $mod_name, $prefix='', $postfix='', $echo=true ) {
        $return = '';
        $mod = get_theme_mod($mod_name);
        if ( ! empty( $mod ) ) {
            $return = sprintf('%s { %s:%s; }',
                $selector,
                $style,
                $prefix.$mod.$postfix
            );
            if ( $echo ) {
                echo $return;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

}

add_action( 'customize_register' , array( 'header_font_color' , 'register' ) );


add_action( 'wp_footer' , array( 'header_font_color' , 'header_outputt' ) );
```

Comment: There’s no code here for changing font size? What did you try?

Comment: I wanted to make the option for the customer to select font size at header as font color. Is there any way to do it without plugin?